# Antd input to get only numeric data with specific limit

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd component to input only numbers and with a max number as well. My code is as follows:

```
                         <Form.Item
                              name="amount"
                              rules={[
                                {
                                  pattern: /^[\d]{0,9}$/,
                                  message: "Value should be less than 999999999",
                                },
                              ]}
                            >
                              <Input
                                type="number"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                  const re = /^[0-9\b]$/;
                                  if ((e.target.value = "" || re.test(e.target.value)))
                                    //use that number
                                }}
                              />
                            </Form.Item>
```

However if I input the letter e or -, it does not give me the form Item validation, is the regex I am writing is wrong?
My requirement is to have:

- Input box that accepts only numerical digits and no - or e character and with a particular maxLength
- This can be achieved by not letting the user type these characters or giving the antd validation msg if either condition fails.

How should I refactor my code to get the desired result? Currently it accepts - digit and does not give any error message. TIA

Comment: Can you not use `<InputNumber/>`. It has min prop where you can put 0 or 1 as value. That way negative number scenario cant be entered. It doesn't except letter anyway so you should be good.

Note - You are able to enter any value into the input but as soon as your focus goes away the value will get set to its default.

`<InputNumber min={1} max={10} value={value} onChange={setValue} />`

Comment: I dont want it to go to default on it's own, I want the user to be told explicitly about the error

Comment: In that case you should use Formik and Yup for form handling, this will fit the bill.

Comment: Does the regex /^[0-9]{0,9}$/ do what you want?